# Ubuntu start with create new user page

Tags: 20.04, login, users, login-screen

My operating system is ubuntu20.04.
Recently, when I turn on my laptop the new user creation page pops up.
I have to create a new user before logging to the desired user.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: How long was your Ubuntu system installed before this began happening?

Comment: My operating system was already ubuntu 19.04 .I had this problem for three months on this operating system. So I changed my operating system to ubuntu 20.04.But this problem was not solve.

Comment: Hey mohammad! Can you please add a photo of the issue which you're facing?